# Calculating cumulative probabilities based on population demograhpics

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

The average American woman has a height of 168.1cm, with a standard deviation of 5.3cm. A girl is 178.1 cm tall, we have 354 girls at our faculty. What is the chance/probablity that exactly 2 girls are smaller than her?

Comment: If this is self-study you need to tag it and tell us how far you have got and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that the girls at your faculty are representative of the population (hint: it's not), then you can borrow some distributional information. Height is approximately normally distributed in the population.

Using this information, we can estimate that the probability of 1 randomly sampled girl being taller than 178.1cm is: $Z = (168.1 - 178.1) / 5.3 = -1.88$ which has a cumulative probability 97% for a randomly sampled woman to be taller than her.

Using binomial probability to account for the chances two and only two women are shorter than her, we calculate: choose(353, 2) * 0.03^2 * 0.97^351 which is of itself not very likely. With such a large sample you should consider cumulative probabilities.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without Z-Score, i mean without taking average(168.1)?  i mean i am only given the height of the girl 178.1 cm, total girls 354 and asked for those two girls? :-) thanks for your help

Comment: @KhanSaab consider Chebyshev's inequality as a more conservative means to estimate the cumulative probability for a randomly selected woman.